# NullPointer exception while listing files and folder in nexus 7 Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, file, directory

I am very confuse the same code working in samsung tab2 but getting issue in nexus 7 Kikat 4.4.2 tablet

```
      @Override    
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_directory);  

        String globalPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";
        getDirectory(globalPath);

      }

  public void getDirectory(String globalPath){

     File directory = new File(globalPath);
     File[] listDirectory = directory.listFiles();


     // Directory
        for(int i=0; i<listDirectory.length;i++)
        {
                File getFolder = listDirectory[i];
                if(getFolder.isDirectory())
                {
                    listFolders.add(getFolder.getName());
                }
         }
 }
```

Logcat:-

```
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): Process: com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app, PID: 7080
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app/com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app.ActivityDirectory}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app.ActivityDirectory.getDirectory(ActivityDirectory.java:92)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app.ActivityDirectory.onCreate(ActivityDirectory.java:48)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-29 15:11:45.870: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     ... 11 more
```

If anyone have idea.Please reply.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found silly mistake i didn't gave permission for sdcard in Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I hope this will others.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

insted of `getDirectory(path);`

put `getDirectory(globalPath);`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But same thing there was some typing mistake.I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

It causes because some devices returns `null` if directory list is empty. Catch it via `try-catch` block.